# flag-controlled while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class flag_controlled_loop {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        char letter;
        String vowels="aeiouAEIOU", enter;
        boolean guess=false;



        while(!guess){
            enter=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter letter: ");
            //letter=enter.charAt(0);

            if(enter.contains(vowels)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found a vowel");
                guess=true;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not that as I am expecting. Try again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is the program should terminate if the letter entered was vowel. i'm just a beginner in programming and I tried this solution but it still won't work. It will skip the if condition. any suggestions please? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the `contains` to a regex, as it is currently looking for the literal String `aeiouAEIOU`

The regex is as follows:

```
enter.contains("[aeiouAEIOU]+");
```

This will return `true` if 'enter' contains a vowel, and `false` if it doesn't.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the regex another solution would be to keep the vowels in a `HashSet` and then use the `contains` method of `HashSet`. Somewhat like this:

```
Set<String> vowels = new HashSet<String>(){{
   add("a");
   add("e");.....
}}
```

and then

```
if(vowels.contains(enter)){..
```

The lookup time would be O(1) in this case.

Comment: ...Not positive (haven't learned HashSet yet), but I think you need to swap 'vowels' and 'enter' in that last line.

Comment: Nope! the `contains` method is defined on HashSet. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:
Creating a boolean variable:

```
      boolean getIT=false;
      while(!guess){
        enter=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter letter: ");
```

Use a for loop to iterate the vowels string:

```
           for(int i = 0; i<vowels.length(); i++){
              letter = vowels.charAt(i);
             // when you get the right vowel set getIT = true; and exit from loop
              if(letter== enter.charAt(0)){
                  getIT = true;
                 break;
              }
               }
              if(getIT){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found a vowel");
                  guess=true;
              }
              else{
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not that as I am expecting. Try again");
              }


    }
```

Comment: Very interesting solution! Might wanna format/comment it a bit differently, as at first glance it looks like the second if statement is part of the for loop. Just maybe line the closing bracket for the loop up with the word 'for'.